# Laplacian matrix eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

Let $L$ be the laplacian of a connected graph.
Is the maximum eigenvalue of $A=\begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} -L$  different than $1$??

Comment: are the $0$s here block matrices?  In other words, could we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0} - L?
$$

Comment: Yes $I$ is the identity matrix therefore your example is absolutely correct

Comment: Are you specifically referring to the maximum eigenvalue, or are you asking whether any eigenvalue can be $1$?

Comment: I'm referring to the maximum eigenvalue

Comment: However, using the gershgorin's theorem you can prove that all eigenvalues of A are less or equal than 1 ;)

Comment: Do you mean maximum in terms of absolute value?  For example, if $A$ had an eigenvalue of $-2$, would that be a counterexample?

Comment: No, I'm referring to maximum with sign

Answer (score 1):

The statement is equivalent to asking whether 
$$
A - I = -\left(\pmatrix{0&0\\0&I} + L\right)
$$
Is necessarily invertible.  My intuition is that this is not the case, but I'm still hunting for a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Let $J$ be the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Let's assume by absurd that the maximum eigenvalues of $A$ is $1$, then 
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
\left ( J-L\right )x_{max,A}=x_{max,A}
\end{equation}
where $x_{max,A}$ is the maximum eigenvector of $A$ related to $\lambda_{max,A}=1$, that is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

Right multiply the first eq by $x_{max,J}^T$
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
x_{max,J}^TJx_{max,A}-x_{max,J}^TLx_{max,A}=x_{max,J}^Tx_{max,A}
\end{equation}
$J$ is symmetric then $x_{max,J}^TJ=1x_{max,J}^T$ therefore
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
x_{max,J}^TLx_{max,A}=0
\end{equation}

But $x_{max,J}^T=[1\,0\,...\,0]$ then $x_{max,A}=[1\,...\,1]$, since L is sum for row null.

But from the first eq  $x_{A}$ can not be equal to $[1\,...\,1]$ unless $J$ is the identity matrix.

What do you think?

Comment: Wy are you able to conclude that $x^T J = 1x^T$?

Comment: Because $Jx=1x$ and J is symmetric

Comment: $Jx \neq 1x$ (necessarily), remember that $J$ has some zeros in it

Comment: never mind, I see now.

Comment: But I'm referring to the maximum eigenvalue, and it is 1

Comment: What do you think about?

Comment: $x^T_{max,J}$ only needs to be $[1\; 0\; \ldots]$ if $J$ has only the one $1$.  It's clear why $x_{max,(-L)}$ is $[-1\; \ldots\; 1]$, but not why you've said that $x_{max,A}$ should be the same.

Comment: Since $J$ and $L$ are Hermitian, we can find the eigenvalues of $A$ by looking at the values of $x^T A x = x^T J x - x^T L x$ (for example, using the Courant-Fischer method).  Since $L$ is positive semi-definite, we have $x^T A x \geq x^T J x$, but without strict inequality we're stuck there.

Comment: Since $x_{max,J}$ is a versor, it selects one row of L, let me name this row $L_i$. So $L_ix_{max,A}$ is equal to zero iff $x_{max,A}$ is equal to [1 1 ...1].

Comment: and $x_{max,J}$ is equal to a versor because J has at least one 1 on the diagonal.